# Why isn't ICMP routing with iptables nat routing

Tags: router, iptables, nat, icmp

I'm using iptables on Ubuntu server to route a public IP to a private IP.  I want to nat all traffic, including 80, 443 and ICMP.

However, it appears that ICMP isn't routing.  I have a steady ping going to the public IP and it never stops, even with NAT pointing to a bogus IP.

Here are the rules that I'm using:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 206.72.119.76 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.240.5.5  
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING  -s 10.240.5.5 -j SNAT --to-source 206.72.119.76
```

I tried with rules for ICMP specifically, but no such luck:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 206.72.119.76 - icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DNAT --to-destination 10.240.5.5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I should mention that port 80 and 3389 routing does work perfectly so I know that everything else is setup correctly.  It's just ICMP that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done any pcapping to see if the icmp packets are getting NAT'd and sent out again?  Maybe they're just being accepted by the box you're running `iptables` on.

Comment: I believe that is what is happening, that the box running iptables is responding, rather than passing the requests on.  I want to ensure that the requests are passed along so that a failure on the end machine causes the pings to start failing.